# Excel 2016: Runtime Error 429 ActiveX component can't create object

Tags: excel, vba, runtime

Excel worksheet been working happily for many months.
This error was reported by a Excel 365 user. 
I tested the actions out on the master copy (using excel 2016) and get exactly the same error[code]

```
ThisWorkbook.Sheets(asSheetNames).Copy

Dim wb As Workbook

' new workbook created as a result of the copy operation should be last
' in the workbooks list
Set wb = Workbooks(Workbooks.Count)

' make it unlocked

' -------------------------------------------
' declare variable for LockXLS Runtime object
Dim oLockXLS As Object
' create LockXLS Runtime object
Set oLockXLS = CreateObject("LockXLSRuntime.Connect")
' unlock new workbook
Call oLockXLS.UnlockWorkbook(wb)
Set oWorkbook = Nothing
```

The error is reported on the line containing statement `Set oLockXLS = CreateObject`

I tested an earlier master version and get exactly the same error

Anyone got an idea of what might have happened and how I might set about fixing this?

Comment: Doesn't look like an issue in VBA looks like an issue with LockXLS. Is the software installed correctly on the computer? Maybe you can try to re-install LockXLS? Make sure the LockXLS Runtime is available on your computer. • If that doesn't help ask here for support: http://www.lockxls.com/contact.asp

Comment: Try reinstalling the add-in. Are you sure it is supported with the new version of Excel?